# Lanch android app from voice command like google assistant

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm building an android app which is all voice control .i would like to open it from voice command like 'OK Google' in google assistant..i have done some research but no luck .i wonder if there is a way or not ..
Really appreciated some help or guide.

Answer (score 0):

I Recently contacted Action On Google support, I wanted to open a feature in my app with google assistant voice command here is there response

The 'MyActivity' can't be accessed by voice within the Assistant. The option itself is built in the Assistant.

As a workaround to access it, is to send the query 'my activity' to the assistant which will prompt the end user if they want to view or delete searches from the 'MyActivity' section. Then, by send the very same query again, will open the 'MyActivity Page', since this is a webpage, there is limited functionality within.